# How to list resources of linked AWS accounts using AWS Go sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-organizations, aws-sdk-go-v2

This is what I have tried. The code below fetches a list of linked accounts, but fetches the list of domains of only one AWS account. I want to list domains or any other resources of each particular linked account.

The problem seems to be around `svc := route53.New(sess)` or the `sess` itself as an account Id is not pass to `svc` or `sess`. So the question is how to pass the account Id?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/organizations"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/route53domains"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/route53"
)

func main() {

    // Load the Shared AWS Configuration (~/.aws/config)
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithDefaultRegion("us-east-1"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create an Amazon service clients
    awsOrgClient := organizations.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    awsRoute53DomainsClient := route53domains.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // Build the request with its input parameters
    resp, err := awsOrgClient.ListAccounts(context.TODO(), &organizations.ListAccountsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to list tables, %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Accounts:")
    for _, account := range resp.Accounts {
        fmt.Println(*account.Name)

        // Build the request with its input parameters
        resp, err := awsRoute53DomainsClient.ListDomains(context.TODO(), &route53domains.ListDomainsInput{}, func(o *route53domains.Options) {})

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to list tables, %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Accounts:")
        for _, route53 := range resp.Domains {
            fmt.Println(*&route53.DomainName)
        }

        // fetch list of domains from AWS Route53
        sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
            SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
        }))

        svc := route53.New(sess)

        // call svc.ListHostedZones() for an account

        result, err := svc.ListHostedZones(&route53.ListHostedZonesInput{})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return
        }

        for _, hostedzone := range result.HostedZones {
            fmt.Println(*hostedzone.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running the AWS Organizations `ListAccounts()` command to obtain a list of accounts.

If you then want to make API calls to each 'member' account, your code will need to **assume an IAM Role** in the member account. This is because your existing credentials are associated with the Organizations account, which does not have permission to access the member accounts.

From [Accessing and administering the member accounts in your organization - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html):

> If you create an account by using the tools provided as part of AWS Organizations, you can access the account by using the preconfigured role named `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` that exists in all new accounts that you create this way.

Thus, you could call `AssumeRole()` on `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` in the member account, which will then return a set of temporary credentials. You can use those credentials to make API calls to the member account.

Basically, a set of credentials will only work with one account.